# Microsoft Excel frozen - Not Allowed to Edit or Reboot

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, freeze

I am glad to find this site as I have been completely stumped on this one. I originally opened a document for a client this morning on excel and attempted to delete a formula for SUM in Column D. I don't think the location of the particular cell has much to do with anything, but like I said, I am stumped!

Once I deleted the SUM formula, my selection is stuck on that cell, and I can not click away from it on the spreadsheet though my cursor is still there. When I go to close Excel to reboot it and give that a try, I receive the message

> Cannot Quit Microsoft Excel

I have also tried restarting my entire computer to no avail, I need your help!

Comment: Have you tried opening excel in safe mode to see if the problem persists? You can do this by holding ctrl and then clicking on the excel shortcut.

Comment: Also, kill the process in the task manager and (apologies for stating the obvious) make sure you completely restart... don't just sleep and re-open. Last thing... if you've solved this issue, please let us know or delete the question.

Comment: Safe Mode fix is not working, it still opens Excel on that same frozen document since I am unable to close the spreadsheet :/ I will be trying the second suggestion now!

Comment: I killed the process in the task manager and completely restarted, I had the capability to delete contents of cells but again when I went to edit the SUM formula, it is now frozen in the same way that it was before? @Owen

Comment: do it again but this time turn the calculations to manual before deleting.  You may also want to ensure no events are firing that may cause the program to go into a never ending loop.

Comment: I cannot access the "File" tab to turn the calculations to Manual, I have a cursor on the spreadsheet and can access my other options (Insert, Data, View, etc.) I am wondering if this is a compatibility issue with the Windows 8 we are running, but even when setting it to Windows 8 I had the same result!

Comment: then my guess is that there is some vba code that fires on the worksheet change event and when deleting the formulas it is causing an indefinite loop.

Comment: and I can't access my vba code without my "File" tab.. I have tried Alt+F11

Comment: Then we are at a loss on how to help you.  You will need to get with the person who created the workbook and talk to them.

Comment: I appreciate the help!

Comment: Few more things to try: 1) find and either delete or rename the personal macro workbook. 2) if the file extension is xlsm, then change it to xlsx (to disable the macros). 3) open the file in an archive manager (i.e. an unzip program) and browse to the "xl/worksheets" folder, then open the .xml file for the sheet with the problem and edit it to remove the SUM in the offending cell. Not 100% sure about this, so proceed with caution. 4) make a copy of the file and try to open that. 5) repair Excel

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure this will work, but it may help.

Make a copy of your file before you begin and do the following on the copy.

I created a test file with some numbers and a simple formula:

[image]

I saved this file as testunzip2.xlsx (because testunzip.xlsx was in unavailable due to reasons).

My goal is to remove that formula without opening the file in Excel.

Fun fact: Excel files since 2007 (I think) are actually zip files.

I right-click the file in Windows Explorer, and because I have 7-Zip installed, I choose '7-Zip>Open archive':

[image]

Your archive manager may be something else. Or you may not have one. If you don't, then... well, get one or stop reading this.

The guts of the file:

[image]

Inside the "xl" folder:

[image]

Note the calcChain.xml file. Inside the "worksheets" folder:

[image]

Now I right-click the Sheet1.xml and choose "Edit". This opens the file from within the Archive in Notepad, or whichever text file editor you have assigned .xml files to. I've found the cell and the function I want to remove:

[image]

I delete everything for that cell:

```
<c r="D2"><f>SUM(B2:B5)</f><v>10</v></c>
```

So, the < c > tags delineate the cell and the < f > tags delineate the function itself.

Now I close the file and save it in its original location (i.e. inside the archive).

At my first attempt, I stopped here and Excel threw a fit when I tried to open the file, saying there was a problem in calcChain.xml. So, I opened calcChain.xml (see image above).

My calcChain.xml only contained one calculation:

[image]

First I tried deleting just the < c/ > tag, but that caused a catastrophic error in Excel, so I tried deleting the file, and no errors when I opened the file. Your calcChain.xml file is likely much more complex with all the calculations for the whole workbook, so you will have to edit that carefully if you choose to try this.

After removing the problem cell and function from the worksheet's xml and any reference to it in calcChain.xml, I was able to open the file again in Excel with no error and the function was gone from the offending cell.